# ESRI js API Date Time Picker

Tags: gis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I'm using a Feature Layer with a Date field type, and I can see in the database that this is a datetime field, and would like to use a datetime picker in the js editor.  I've tried using a jquery datetime picker, and cannot override the default ESRI/Dojo date picker.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: First question would normally be "what have you already tried?", but this is a particularly garbage part of the JS API (IMO), so instead - is there a particular reason why you want to use the jQuery datepicker over the Dojo one?

Comment: If I can get the date picker to be a date time picker, I'd use the dojo one... I've tried a custom dijit, jquery date time picker, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom dijit in your editor is the correct solution. You need to tell the editor to use a different dijit when displaying the edit window:

...

```
var editSettings = {
    map: myMap,
    layerInfos: {
        "featureLayer": myLayer,
        "infoTemplate": myTemplate,
        "fieldInfos": [
             {'fieldName':'DATESTUFFHAPPENED','label':'Stuff Happened','customField':new dijit.form.DateTimeWidget({options_go_here})}
        ]
    }
};
var params = {settings: editSettings};
var editor = new esri.dijit.editing.Editor(params, 'my-div');
```

There's a possible custom widget [here](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/10352) that you might find useful?

Comment: That gets me close, but that widget is not really a help. It's a good start, I may just have to write my own dijit

Comment: Unfortunately, that may turn out to be your best option. One more suggestion out of left field - use `customField` as above to force it to display a standard text box (with no fancy dojo stuff) and see if you can hook the jQuery datetime picker onto that?